# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null at Measure._deleteTip

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.key == 'Escape') {
        this._deleteTip();
      }
    });

    _deleteTip() {
     //get Div {id: tip}
     const e = document.getElementById('tip');

     e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
     return true;
   }
```

After create a div element via javaScript, press Escape key to destroyd the div and get measure.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null at Measure._deleteTip. Anyone knows how to resolve it?

Comment: Where's your html? It may be related

Comment: Evidently, no element with the ID `tip` exists.